# How do I put a kernel density estimate on top of a basemap in R?

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am able to export my kde as a shapefile to use in ArcGIS but I'm wondering if I can put it on top of a basemap in R instead to show the homerange of my species.

This is how I created the kde:

````
library(sp)
gps_data_121130 <- read.csv('gps_data_121130.csv')
gps_points <- SpatialPoints(gps_data_121130[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")], 
                            proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
cord.UTM <- spTransform(gps_points, CRS("+init=epsg:32748"))
kde <- kernelUD(cord.UTM, h = "href", grid = 100, kern = "bivnorm")
kde50 <- getverticeshr(kde, percent = 50)
plot(kde50, col = "red", lwd = 2, main = "50% KDE of GPS data")```

I have tried a couple of things but can't seem to get this on top of a map as it is now in R. I tried to make it a raster but I am getting an error. Also, I wasn't sure what lat and lon to use.
r1 <- raster(kde50)
bm <- ggmap(get_map(location = c(lon = -155.84, lat = 19.74), 
                    maptype = "terrain"))

bm + inset_raster(as.raster(r1), xmin = r1@extent[1], xmax = r1@extent[2],
                  ymin = r1@extent[3], ymax = r1@extent[4])

Error in `get_googlemap()`:
! Google now requires an API key; see `ggmap::register_google()`.
Backtrace:
 1. ggmap::ggmap(...)
 2. ggmap::get_map(...)
 3. ggmap::get_googlemap(...)

Here is a sample of my dataset:

DeployID    Date    Latitude    Longitude
121130  8/22/2012 1:20  47.677  -122.137
121130  8/22/2012 1:28  47.677  -122.136
121130  8/22/2012 1:32  47.677  -122.135
121130  8/22/2012 3:00  47.678  -122.136

Thank you!
````

Comment: It looks like the problem is related to the API key you need for `ggmap::get_map`. Do you have an API key?

Comment: I am not familiar with that so I assume I do not. I need one of those to use ggmap?

Comment: Apparently so. The documentation for `ggmap` will tell how to get it.

Comment: I didn't realize you had to pay for an API key. Do you know of another package that is good for creating maps in R that I can overlay my kde on?

Comment: You have to pay? Hmm. Not cool. You have many other options. The `tmap` package is pretty easy for mapping multiple objects and including a basemap. Here is a good tutorial: https://r.geocompx.org/adv-map.html

Comment: you have to supply a credit card, but you _may_ not get charged. It depends if you go over the limits etc.